# Отображение всего рисунка

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Есть код

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        all__buttons=document.querySelectorAll('.header__button');
        /*selected__button.click= function(){
                selected__button.backgroundColor='#5f3ec0';
            
        };*/
    /*
        function changeColor(inputbutton) {
            inputbutton.style.backgroundColor='#5f3ec0';
        
        }
        
    */
    
            [].forEach.call(all__buttons, function(selected__button){
                selected__button.addEventListener('click', function(event){
                    event.target.style.backgroundColor='#5f3ec0';
                    event.target.style.color='#ffffff';
                
                });
            }); 
    }
    )
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.globalcontainer {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 4%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 4%;
    height: 100%;
}

.header > .header__text {
position: relative;
width: 93px;
height: 24px;
left: 0;
margin-top: 129px;
margin-bottom: 20px;

font-family: TT Norms;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 100%;
/* identical to box height, or 24px */


color: #000000;
}

/*
.header__buttons {
    left: 0;
    top: 193px;
}
*/


.header__button {
    width: 75px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-right: 1.75%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.header__buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 7px 15px 7px 0px;
    /*margin-right: 10%;*/
}

.mobileimage {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="testsite.css">-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/mobile.css" media="screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 639px)"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/tablet.css" media="screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 1023px)"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/desktop.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1920px)"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="globalcontainer">
        <div class="header">
                <div class="header__text">
                    Обзоры
                </div>
                <div class="header__buttons">
                    <!-- <span> -->
                        <button class="header__button">Все</button>
                        <button class="header__button">Видео</button>               
                        <button class="header__button">Текст</button>               
                        <button class="header__button">Обзоры</button>
                        <button class="header__button">Сравнения</button>
                        <button class="header__button">Краш видео</button>
                        <button class="header__button">Распаковка</button>
                    <!-- </span> -->
                </div>
        </div>      
        <div class="content">       
                <div class="cardexample">
                    <div class="mobileimage">
                        <img src="../img/mobileimage.png"></img>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="cardexample">
                </div>
                <div class="cardexample">
                </div>
                <div class="cardexample">
                </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsactions.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Страница отображается так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а необходимо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как уместить весь рисунок?

Comment: `max-width: 100%` ?

Comment: @teran нет `max-width` не помогло. Даже `width: 100%` не помогло.

Comment: так и приписали небось не к `img` ?

Comment: @teran в `.mobileimage` написал (см. последнюю строчку css кода)

Comment: @teran это mobile first, резина - может это как-то повлияло?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы указываете ширину для блока `mobileimage`, но не для картинки в нем.

```css
.mobileimage{
  /* ширина блока для примера */
  width: 400px;
}
.mobileimage img{
  /* тут вся магия */
  max-width: 100%;
  /* height:auto потому, что некоторые браузеры при растягивании картинки, не сохраняют пропорции */
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobileimage">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAZMn.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
```

И еще `img` - это одиночный тег, а не парный.
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img